# Separate filters for api and mvc endpoints in ASP.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Is there a way to separate filters for my MVC controllers and ones used for web api purposes? Something like:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
     options.Filters.Add(new Filter1()); //MVC           
     options.Filters.Add(new Filter2());//web api only?
});
```

Comment: When you're talking about ASP.Net Core controllers, how do you divide them into MVC and Web API controllers? In ASP.Net Core all controllers are derived from the same class - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`.

Comment: @CodeFuller i understand that, but i've separated my controllers in to two separate folders and namespaces. I guess there should be a way to separate filters as old MVC and WebApi had.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in comments, in ASP.Net Core there is no separation of MVC and Web API controllers. All controllers are derived from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`.

It's completely different from ASP.NET MVC and Web API, where filters and filter collections belong to two different universes.

So you can't expect that ASP.Net Core will provide you built-in way to separate filters based on your conditions. `MvcOptions` has the only `Filters` collection.

However you could easily cover your requirement by having an action filter that aggregates other application filters and 'know' whether it's Web Api or Mvc action and whether the underlying filter should be executed.

Here is a sample:

```
public class SeparateActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private enum FilterType
    {
        Mvc,
        WebApi
    }

    private readonly IActionFilter innerFilter;
    private readonly FilterType filterType;

    public static IActionFilter MvcFilter(IActionFilter innerFilter)
    {
        return new SeparateActionFilter(innerFilter, FilterType.Mvc);
    }

    public static IActionFilter WebApiFilter(IActionFilter innerFilter)
    {
        return new SeparateActionFilter(innerFilter, FilterType.WebApi);
    }

    private SeparateActionFilter(IActionFilter innerFilter, FilterType filterType)
    {
        this.innerFilter = innerFilter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerFilter));
        this.filterType = filterType;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (ShouldExecute(context))
        {
            innerFilter.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (ShouldExecute(context))
        {
            innerFilter.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldExecute(FilterContext context)
    {
        return filterType == FilterType.Mvc && IsMvcFilter(context) ||
                filterType == FilterType.WebApi && !IsMvcFilter(context);
    }

    private bool IsMvcFilter(FilterContext context)
    {
        //  You logic for separation of MVC and Web Api filters.
        //  You could make checks on context.ActionDescriptor, context.HttpContext or context.RouteData.

        return true;
    }
}
```

Registering filters:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(SeparateActionFilter.MvcFilter(new Filter1()));    // MVC 
    options.Filters.Add(SeparateActionFilter.WebApiFilter(new Filter2())); //   web api only
});
```

You only have to implement `IsMvcFilter()` method with separation logic between MVC and Web API filters. In this method you have an access to `FilterContext` with all required information like `ActionDescriptor`, `HttpContext` and `RouteData`.

Comment: could this work with TypeFilterAttributes and IAsyncActionFilters?

Comment: This approach will work with any filter. You just need to slightly adjust the code for the filters you are going to use.

Comment: this approach will use the same instance of the filter for every requests! Be very very careful